# Rename doctype in elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I used [elasticsearch-py](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/) to move millions of records represented by a Django model from PostgreSQL to Elasticsearch. 
I used the name of the model for doctype (which was in CamelCase).

I then switched to [Elasticsearch DSL](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and noticed that by default it creates doctypes with lowercase names with underscores (snake_case).

I don't want to redefine `doc_type` in my document meta, so I am to rename it in Elasticsearch. What would be the fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

My own solution using `elasticsearch_dsl`:

```or-tag-here
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import connections


connection = connections.get_connection()    
s = Search(index=index, doc_type=old_name)

actions = (dict(
    _index=hit.meta.index, _type=new_name, 
    _id=hit.meta.id, _source=hit.to_dict()
) for hit in s.scan())
bulk(connection, actions, request_timeout=300)
s.params(request_timeout=600).delete()
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to group actions into chunks yourself, the `bulk` helper already does that, you can feed it directly an iterator (a generator in this case) that will consume the `scan` results and `yield` out the modified docs.

Comment: Thank you @HonzaKrál. Updated.